# Why attacks against Muslims are termed as Islamophobia but it is not Kaffirphobia when Muslims attack others?

Tags: quran, islamic-government

I believe instead of Islamophobia there should be a general resolution in the UN to discourage attacks against other faiths because there are many incidents where Muslims have attacked people of other religions or non-muslims living in a muslim country have received hate crime and death threat. Just recently in Pakistan, multiple churches were destroyed by fanatic Muslims in Jaranwala. Why shouldnt these attacks be termed as Kaffirphobia if attacks on Muslims can be termed as Islamophobia?

Comment: This is a rant, not a question on Islamic teachings.

Comment: @UmH No this is not. I am asking why don't muslims condemn general atrocities against people of other faiths instead of just condemning islamophobia.

Answer (score -1):

The term "Islamophobia" and the concept of addressing religious discrimination are not meant to diminish or ignore the suffering or attacks experienced by people of other faiths. Let me clarify a few key points:

**1. Islamophobia and Religious Discrimination:**
Islamophobia specifically refers to the irrational fear, hatred, or prejudice against Islam and Muslims. It is a term used to address discrimination and bias against Muslims due to their religious beliefs. It does not inherently imply that attacks against people of other faiths are less important or should be ignored. The term is used to highlight a particular issue, just as terms like "antisemitism" or "anti-Christian sentiments" are used to address discrimination against Jewish or Christian communities.

**2. Universal Human Rights:**
The United Nations Universal Declaration of Human Rights and various international conventions protect the rights and freedoms of people of all religions and beliefs. These documents condemn discrimination, hatred, and violence against any religious or ethnic group. There is no need for a separate term like "Kaffirphobia" to address attacks against non-Muslims, as such attacks are already covered under broader international human rights frameworks.

**3. Addressing Discrimination as a Whole:**
The goal should be to promote religious tolerance and respect for all faiths and beliefs, not to create terms that single out one group or another. It is important to work towards a world where people of all religions can coexist peacefully and without fear of discrimination or violence.

**4. Local and International Response:**
Incidents like the destruction of churches in Pakistan or attacks on religious minorities anywhere in the world should be condemned and addressed by both local authorities and the international community. This can involve legal actions against perpetrators, raising awareness of religious freedom, and promoting interfaith dialogue and understanding.

In summary, while addressing specific issues like Islamophobia is important, the broader goal should be to promote religious tolerance, respect, and the protection of human rights for all individuals, regardless of their religious beliefs. Discrimination and violence against any religious group should be condemned and addressed through existing international frameworks for human rights and religious freedom.

Comment: Was this written by ChatGPT?